# php loop multidimensional array

Tags: php

Hello i trying to fetch multidimensional array. I know how to do that but am not shure what is the best way to get information from main array item...

See example:

```
$this->toolbar = array(
    'add' => array(
        'class' => 'add_icon32',
        'action' => 'controller/add',
        'label' => 'Add'
    ),
    'edit' => array(
        'class' => 'edit_icon32',
        'action' => 'controller/edit',
        'label' => 'Edit'
    ),
);
```

I want to foreach this in one loop. I want result like this

```
<li class="<?php $class"> <a href="<?php $action; ?> "> <?php $label; ?> </a> </li>
```

I try with For but i must define all items separately. Bcs i want foreach to do this. See what i do but this is separately

```
<?php
$data = array(
    'add' => array(
        'action' => 'add/contorler/add/action',
        'class' => 'add_css_class',
        'label' => 'Add'
    ),
    'edit' => array(
        'action' => 'edit/contorler/edit/action',
        'class' => 'edit_css_class',
        'label' => 'Edit'
    )
);?>

<?php for($i = 2; $i<=count($data); ++$i): ?>
    <a class="<?php echo $data['add']['class']?>" href="<?php echo $data['add']['action'];?>"><?php echo $data['add']['label']?></a>
<?php endfor;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php foreach ($data as $val) { ?>
    <a class="<?php echo $val['class'];?>" href="<?php echo $val['action'];?>"><?php echo $val['label'];?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

or

```
foreach ($data as $val) print <<<qq
    <a class="$val[class]" href="$val[action]">$val[label]</a>
qq;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
foreach ($data as $k => $v)
   echo "<a class='$v[class]' href='$v[action]'>$v[label]</a>";
```

Apparently, you don't even need the key `$k`, so just leave it out as in

```
foreach ($data as $v)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    
foreach($this->toolbar as $part){ ?>
   <li class="<?php echo $part['class'] ; ?>">
      <a href="<?php echo $part['action'] ; ?>">
         <?php echo $part['label'] ; ?>
       </a>
    </li>
<?php  
} 
?>
```